# Feature set to controller mapping possible with c++ template inheritance?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, interface, multiple-inheritance

**Background:**
I am trying to build a system in c++, where i have

- a set of features that might be supported by some hardware controllers (but not by others) defined as a number of pure virtual interfaces (`InterfaceA`, `InterfaceB`...)
- a set of controller classes each implementing a subset of the available feature-interfaces
- Classes that realize more complex algorithms requiring some but usually not all features

In a class `AdvancedCodeBuildingOnFeatureSubSet_AB` that requires features A and B i want to be able to have a member pointer to a (non-virtual) controller class to be used.

**'Classic' approach**
I could in principle use a void-pointer and dynamic-cast it into the feature-interface type i want to use (call a function on). This causes a lot of ugly casting and checking. Alternatively i could cast the controller once into each interface required by `AdvancedCodeBuildingOnFeatureSubSet_AB` and store a member pointer typed for each feature interface (obviously ugly as well).

**Template approach (doesnt work at least yet)**
I came up with variadic template inheritance and i wonder if i could use that to achieve a better solution, where i can use a single member pointer

`InterfaceCollection<InterfaceA, InterfaceB>* m_Controller`

to access features from `InterfaceA` and `InterfaceB`. Therein, `InterfaceCollection` could be similar to

```
template <class... T>
class InterfaceCollection : public T... {
};
```

inheriting from Interface A and B.
However, that way `InterfaceCollection<InterfaceA, InterfaceB>*` and `InterfaceCollection<InterfaceA, InterfaceB>*` are not the same type and thus incompatible (although for all practical reasons they are compatible because they inherit both A and B). Below is a minimal (non-) working example to copy&paste.

**I do understand why this does not work, but is there a way to fix it?**
( and e.g. make the template inheritance transparent to the template type evaluation during compile time or the like?)

**Minimal Example**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



// pure virtual interface to provide feature A
class InterfaceA {
public:
    virtual void do_Feature_A() = 0;
};

// pure virtual interface to provide feature B
class InterfaceB {
public:
    virtual void do_Feature_B() = 0;
};
// pure virtual interface to provide feature C
class InterfaceC {
public:
    virtual void do_Feature_C() = 0;
};



// Helper to implement multiple interfaces ... (?)
template <class... T>
class InterfaceCollection : public T... {

};



// real controllers implementing different selections of features from different interfaces
class Controller_A_Capable : public InterfaceCollection<InterfaceA> {
public:
    Controller_A_Capable() {};
    void do_Feature_A() {/*do sth.*/};
};

class Controller_AB_Capable : public InterfaceCollection<InterfaceA, InterfaceB> {
public:
    Controller_AB_Capable() {};
    void do_Feature_A() {/*do sth.*/};
    void do_Feature_B() {/*do sth.*/};
};
class Controller_ABC_Capable : public InterfaceCollection<InterfaceA, InterfaceB, InterfaceC> {
public:
    Controller_ABC_Capable() {};
    void do_Feature_A() {/*do sth.*/};
    void do_Feature_B() {/*do sth.*/};
    void do_Feature_C() {/*do sth.*/};
};




class AdvancedCodeBuildingOnFeatureSubSet_AB {
public:
    AdvancedCodeBuildingOnFeatureSubSet_AB(InterfaceCollection<InterfaceA, InterfaceB>* controller) : m_Controller(controller){};
    InterfaceCollection<InterfaceA, InterfaceB>* m_Controller;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //different realized controllers
    Controller_A_Capable* controllerA = new Controller_A_Capable();
    Controller_AB_Capable* controllerAB = new Controller_AB_Capable();
    Controller_ABC_Capable* controllerABC = new Controller_ABC_Capable();

    //doesnt compile: okay
    AdvancedCodeBuildingOnFeatureSubSet_AB* test1 = new AdvancedCodeBuildingOnFeatureSubSet_AB(controllerA); 

    //compiles: exact match
    AdvancedCodeBuildingOnFeatureSubSet_AB* test2 = new AdvancedCodeBuildingOnFeatureSubSet_AB(controllerAB); 

    //DOES NOT COMPILE: NOT OKAY
    AdvancedCodeBuildingOnFeatureSubSet_AB* test3 = new AdvancedCodeBuildingOnFeatureSubSet_AB(controllerABC); ;)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the classic OOP way in C++ to achieve that is through multiple inheritance.

Comment: [Something along these lines](http://rextester.com/CLV25307), perhaps?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks for the idea - i didn't know std::get until now. It indeed shortens the castings and is typesafe. Unfortunately my vs2012 compiler does not support the get yet. However that is going to change soon... ;)